# Guy is drugged and wakes up on a spaceship and has to fight aliens to protect new earth

Tags: story-identification, books, spaceship, space

It's a book about a guy that was in the military but he is drugged and wakes up on a spaceship I think called the Ark. The ship has traveled to a new world and now they have to fight the aliens that invaded earth to protect new earth.

Comment: Hi Seth. You haven't given us a lot to go on. Is there anything else you can remember? Any detail, no matter how trivial, can help to jog memories.

Answer (score 4):

These points align well with "[Genesis](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2361027)", the first book in the "First Colony Series" by Ken Lozito.

The protoagonist is Colonel Connor Grant. He heads a special ops team in an operation that goes horribly wrong. To keep him out of the way, the authorities arrange for him to be kidnapped and put in cryostasis aboard a colony ship called the "Ark". He wakes up 200 years later when the ship has arrived at its destination, and must use his military skills to defend the colony from the alien lifeforms on the planet. In the subsequent books he also develops a space navy to fight aliens that invaded Earth during the 200 year interval.